# Is emulator emulating emulation?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

We have two tags [emulator](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/emulator) and [emulation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/emulation), each with around 130 questions. The questions seem to me to be covering the same range of topics.

Should one be a synonym of the other (I prefer *emulation* which sounds like a topic)? Or should something else be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [emulation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/emulation) has at least a sensible excerpt while [emulator](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/emulator) has none I agree with your proposal to keep *emulation* and make *emulator* a synonym.

Answer (score 3):

Beside what you have proposed is completely logical, if we look up other sites on the network we can see others are taking the same approach.
[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/emulation/synonyms): [emulation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/emulation) main tag. [emulator](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/emulator) synonym.

So... Yeah.